# web design working in direct IE browsing but fails when viewed via IIS

Tags: html, asp.net, css, iis, visual-studio-2012

I have a web template i downloaded and browsed locally by double clicking the .html file. when viewed this way everything works fine.

but when the files are copied to a folder inside an existing Visual Studio project and run such that IIS servers the same .html file the design is off.

the .html is in the same folder with the same sub-folders (css, js, images...) the only distinction is viewing via double click of the file to bring up IE verse having the same file be the start up page and running the VS project.

the failing IIS version is shown in the left of the image and the double clicked and workign version is shown on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the browser mode and document mode from F12 tools and compare the differences between the two renderings. I suspect they are not the same. Also check if one is in compatibility mode and the other is not. This could help to explain the differences in the display of the file.

See [META Tags and Locking in Future Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/cc817574.aspx) for more on how to force IE to render a page in a specific mode.

Comment: nope, compatibility mode ruins the entire UI because its based on html5. the template is free for download: http://usman.it/free-responsive-admin-template/